# I want to extract QSTS_ID column and delimit by full stop and append it to the exisisting list as a seperate column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of8Qe.jpg)When applying the below code , i am getting NAN values in the entire column of QSTS_ID

```
df['QSTS_ID'] = df['QSTS_ID'].str.split('.',expand=True)
df
```

I want to copy the entire QSTS_ID column and append it at the end. I also have to delimit it by fullstop and apply new headers

Comment: When you expand you get multiple columns. Your mistake is in L.H.S. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @coldspeed - Thank you :)

Comment: @jezrael My pleasure. This is my olive branch to you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is if add parameter `expand=True` it return `DataFrame` with one or more columns, so assign return `NaN`s.

Solution is add new columns with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original `DataFrame`, also [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) is for change new columns names:

```
df = df.join(df['QSTS_ID'].str.split('.',expand=True).add_prefix('QSTS_ID_'))

df = pd.concat([df, df['QSTS_ID'].str.split('.',expand=True).add_prefix('QSTS_ID_')], axis=1)
```

If want also remove original column:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('QSTS_ID').str.split('.',expand=True).add_prefix('QSTS_ID_'))

df = pd.concat([df,
                df.pop('QSTS_ID').str.split('.',expand=True).add_prefix('QSTS_ID_')], axis=1)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'QSTS_ID':['val_k.lo','val2.s','val3.t'],
        'F':list('abc')
})

df1 = df['QSTS_ID'].str.split('.',expand=True).add_prefix('QSTS_ID_')
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
    QSTS_ID  F QSTS_ID_0 QSTS_ID_1
0  val_k.lo  a     val_k        lo
1    val2.s  b      val2         s
2    val3.t  c      val3         t

#check columns names of new columns
print (df1.columns)
```

Comment: I am still getting NAN instead of what actually is there in the column when I tried the first method

Comment: @Sca - It seems some data problem. what return `print (df['QSTS_ID'].str.split('.',expand=True).add_prefix('QSTS_ID_')` ?

Comment: this is the error                                                                                          columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['QSTS_ID_0'], dtype='object')

Comment: @Sca - it means there is already column `QSTS_ID_0` in original data, try `df = df.join(df['QSTS_ID'].str.split('.',expand=True).add_prefix('NEW_QSTS_ID_'))`

Comment: I have to make a separate column with the same entries but delimited by fullstop and also add headers to it

Comment: @Sca - Yes, I understand, no idea why not working. Are data confidental? Is possible share it?

Comment: Any way how i can give all those new columns new header names?

Comment: Thru your solution, it is getting added twice.

Comment: @Sca - Check sample solution, it join `df1` by `df = df.join(df1)` only once

Comment: It shows the following error if i do by the sample solution------------    ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['QSTS_ID_0', 'QSTS_ID_1', 'QSTS_ID_2', 'QSTS_ID_3', 'QSTS_ID_4',
       'QSTS_ID_5', 'QSTS_ID_0', 'QSTS_ID_1', 'QSTS_ID_2', 'QSTS_ID_3',
       'QSTS_ID_4', 'QSTS_ID_5'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: @Sca - Not run multiple solution working same? Can you show me your all code by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54230122/edit)?

Comment: I cannot use this part of the sample solution you provided.----- df = pd.DataFrame({
        'QSTS_ID':['val_k.lo','val2.s','val3.t'],
        'F':list('abc')
})   ------------- since I have a lot of entries in the QSTS_ID column

Comment: @Sca - Why? What is problem? Not understand.

Comment: @Sca - I want see your code, not data, because confidental data.